# Orika using BoundMapperFacade instead of MapperFacade

Tags: java, java-8, orika

[Orika Performance Tuning](https://orika-mapper.github.io/orika-docs/performance-tuning.html) guide says

1. `BoundMapperFacade` is more performant than `MapperFacade` &
2. Use a non-cyclic version of `BoundMapperFacade`.

My code looks something like below

```
System.setProperty(OrikaSystemProperties.WRITE_SOURCE_FILES, "false");
System.setProperty(OrikaSystemProperties.WRITE_CLASS_FILES, "false");

MapperFactory factory = new DefaultMapperFactory.Builder().build();

//Then during initialization quite a few code is added to classMap like below with all the classes non cyclic

factory.classMap(Folder.class, FolderUI.class).byDefault().register();
factory.classMap(VCManager.class, VCManagerUI.class).byDefault().register();
factory.classMap(NSXManager.class, NSXManagerUI.class).byDefault().register();
factory.classMap(L3SwitchManager.class, BaseManagerUI.class).byDefault().register();

...

MapperFacade mapper = factory.getMapperFacade();
```

Whenever I need to do a look up I am doing `mapper.map(input, output)`

Can someone let me know how can I use `BoundedMapperFacade` in this case as I don't see any `getBoundedMapperFacade` in `MapperFacade`.

Orika Version - 1.4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MapperFactory gives you the correct class by deciding on the parameters. If you use the method `getMapperFacade()` with the class you want to map from and the class you want to map to, it gives you the `BoundMapperFacade`:

```
BoundMapperFacade<From,To> mapper = mapperFactory.getMapperFacade(From.class, To.class);
```